# How do I keep Scan from reading all characters from a user input in GO?

Tags: validation, go

I am currently trying to validate user input for a random team generator. The user inputs the number of team members per team and the program breaks up the list of names into teams. If I put in a string it outputs an error message for each character in the string. I want it to output just one error message even if I type several characters.

```
//Dan Bell
//Random team generator

package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    var my_slice []string

    // open the names.txt file contained in the same directory
    f, err := os.Open("names.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()
    //scan the contents of the .txt file into a slice
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {

        my_slice = append(my_slice, scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //shuffle the slice so that the groups are random each time
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    rand.Shuffle(len(my_slice), func(i, j int) { my_slice[i], my_slice[j] = my_slice[j], my_slice[i] })

    fmt.Println("\nWelcome to our team generator" + "\n\n\n" + "How big should the teams be?")

    var teamSize int

    //put the user input into the teamSize variable
    //validate input 
    for {
        _, err := fmt.Scan(&teamSize)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("\nEnter a valid number")
        } else {
            break
        }

    }
    // fmt.Scanln(&teamSize)

    var divided [][]string
    //chop the slice into chunks sized using the teamSize entered by a user
    for i := 0; i < len(my_slice); i += teamSize {
        end := i + teamSize

        if end > len(my_slice) {
            end = len(my_slice)
        }

        divided = append(divided, my_slice[i:end])
    }
    //print each group
    for i := 0; i < len(divided); i++ {
        fmt.Println("\nGroup " + fmt.Sprint(i+1) + "\n" + strings.Join(divided[i], ", "))
    }

}
```

Comment: improve this question by hard coding some example data from `names.txt` so we can run the code.

Comment: Why prompt the user for input at all?   Though it's common enough programming instruction books, very few programs prompt for user input this way.   Why not take the team size as a parameter to the program and get it out of `os.Args`, then convert with `strconv`?